# Database credentials in environment variables?

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-boot

Many developers here on Stackoverflow and on other sites recommend to store the database password in an environment variable. We're using Spring Boot and we'd like to know if it's really a good (safe and common) way to avoid clear text passwords in the application.properties file, even in production? If not, what's the better solution?

Mind that we need different .properties-files for DEV and PROD.

Comment: You can use Spring profiles to manage different property files per environment.

Comment: to avoid clear password you can store encrypted password using jasypt

Comment: Look into Hashicorp Vault. If that's not possible then password files owned and readable only by the db user are common. Your app start script reads the password file and puts it in an env var that's referenced in application.properties. Never share the db user for other purposes (e.g. the web server).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to take a look into [Spring Cloud Config](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/):

> Spring Cloud Config provides server and client-side support for
>   externalized configuration in a distributed system. With the Config
>   Server you have a central place to manage external properties for
>   applications across all environments.

Features:

> **Spring Cloud Config Server features:**
>
> - HTTP, resource-based API for external configuration (name-value    pairs, or equivalent YAML content)
> - Encrypt and decrypt property values (symmetric or asymmetric)
> - Embeddable easily in a Spring Boot application using `@EnableConfigServer`
>
> **Config Client features (for Spring applications):**
>
> - Bind to the Config Server and initialize Spring Environment with    remote property sources
> - Encrypt and decrypt property values (symmetric or asymmetric)

You can find a working example of a Config Server [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/configserver)

Answer (score 0):

This is all depending on how you deploy your applications. Spring Boot uses a particular order to how properties are set. See: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

There are different ways of not exposing you password to much but it will always be visible to someone with enough access and if they know where to look.

Eg. If you run you application i docker you might want to set all passwords as environment variables.

But another example is to set them as properties when you start your app

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --property=value
```

You have to choose what fits your needs the best.

Comment: Including a password in the command line will have it show up in the process list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashiCorp Vault with Spring Boot: https://projects.spring.io/spring-vault/ or if you use cloud: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-vault/